# Most GUI user friendly Time series Econometrics software for modelling and Forecasting GARCH models

Tags: time-series, garch, forecasting, econometrics, software

I think the question is simple enough. I have been using Eviews, but it is unable to do recursive one step ahead forecasting directly and requires me to use coding, which I'm not very good at.

I need to know which is the best software which will allow me to do recursive one step ahead forecasts, whereby coefficients are re-estimated at each step, and these are used for forecasts.

Additionally if anyone can also answer the following question linked, it would be highly appreciated.

[Correct procedure for modelling GARCH for forecasting volatility of stock Index returns](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33086/correct-procedure-for-modelling-garch-for-forecasting-volatility-of-stock-index)

Comment: Unless, there is someone on this community who has experience in coding in Eviews and can help me out? I already have the basic code, I just need minor modifications I think, but obviously my knowledge is limited.

Comment: I'm voting to close because "the best software" .. is too opinion based to me.

Comment: Irrespective of my vote to close, for information I do not know a single software that directly allow you to estimate a models whereby coefficients are re-estimated at each step. You 'll be forced to use coding at some points, it looks like a good reason to learn coding, and to add a further skill to your CV.

Comment: I'd be surprised there is any software that is able to do this. If it exists it's probably the best by lack of competition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am now using coding. Does anyone in this community have experience in coding in Eviews? If I post my code can I get a bit of assistance with it in terms of minor tweaks? If I can get an answer to this, I choose to accept and close this discussion.

Comment: Any idea on the previous comment guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the part of your question on

> ...software which will allow me to do recursive one step ahead forecasts, whereby coefficients are re-estimated at each step, and these are used for forecasts.

Automated recursive GARCH estimation and forecasting is available in R package `rugarch` via function [`ugarchroll`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rugarch/versions/1.3-6/topics/ugarchroll-methods) (you will find an example in the link, too). See also the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) for details and examples.

Comment: Thank you. I'm accepting this answer. Would appreciate a response to this question. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271192/sample-to-use-when-doing-arma-order-selection-ols-garch-estimation